# Keep Process.Start() From running at the same time

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem, i was doing files copy and then combine them into pdf file using "pdftk" from cmd.

i put the copy process into a nest loop to get the files i wanted. However, the combine process start at the same time as the copy process run which combines any file already copied. It should wait until the copy done then start the combine. Please help me with this

```
Private Sub PDF_Print(ProcessDir As String)

 Dim i As Integer = 0
 For i = 1 To CInt(txtNumofSet.Text)

Dim Labelcopy As String = "/c S: & cd ""S:\User Files\Shipping & Receiving\NewlyWeds labels\process"" & for /l %x in (1, 1, " & txtCopies.Text & ")" &
                                  "do (copy """ & SourceFile & """ workarea\" & i & "S" & "%x.pdf)"
        Dim Run = Process.Start("cmd.exe", Labelcopy)

        Dim Blankcopy As String = "/c S: & cd ""S:\User Files\Shipping & Receiving\NewlyWeds labels\process"" & for /l %x in (1, 1, " & txtNumofblanks.Text & ")" &
                                  "do (copy """ & ProcessDir & """ workarea\" & i & "SB" & "%x.pdf)"
        Dim Run1 = Process.Start("cmd.exe", Blankcopy)

    Next


    Process.Start("S:\User Files\Shipping & Receiving\NewlyWeds labels\process\Label.cmd")


    ' Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Is there any ways to tell the last the Process.start to start after the first two finish running. Thank you.

Comment: If you insist on using CMD, you can use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .NET framework to copy the files, e.g. [`File.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I used it when i first started coding, but the copy time took so much longer than i did in cmd :(

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [Process.HasExited Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if a process has completed.  Here is a simple example:

```
Dim objProcess As Process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", Labelcopy)

Do Until objProcess.HasExited

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

Loop

Process.Start("S:\User Files\Shipping & Receiving\NewlyWeds labels\process\Label.cmd")
```

Comment: The `Process` class has an [`Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event and a [`WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) method, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Why not post it as an answer?